# Where to store (in which ASP.Net Folder) EF model and related files/classes in ASP.Net Web forms project?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have created ASP.NET Web Forms project.
My question is , In which folder is the best experience (or rule) to store EF model and related files classes [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WiM9.png)

I have read description of all ASP.Net folders, and I could not find any where I can put EF model.
It is my first ASP.Net project and I am afraid to have security issues that anyone can access project files.
Thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: Compiled Source code cannot be accessed from a Web server

Comment: So I can store it anywhere yes? @ErikEJ

Comment: In this case the best folder is the trash folder :) Pun aside, do yourself a favor and don't use EDMX any more. It's near-deprecated technology. When working code-first (or code-first form database) it's all a matter of personal preference where to store model classes. Or even in which project. (Like a separate DAL project).

Comment: @Gert Arnold, could you advice what technology to use instead?

Comment: FOr example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database

Comment: @Gert Arnold, thanks for the advice, but i think i used the same, but database first option, it creates edmx.

Comment: Yes, so choose code-first from database, not EF designer form database.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, yes, now i see. Thanks alot for advice.